# Should I use dewormer on my cat?

Tags: cats

My cat looks perfectly healthy. But the last time that I visited the vet I received a dewormer to apply to his back of neck. 
I'm wondering if this is absolutely necessary?

I suspect that this is yet another marketing ploy to sell a product whose benefits (if any) does not outweigh harms due to chemical compounds. After all for 50 million years felines did not use deworm products and that does not seem to not bother them much.

Answer (score 4):

If your cat spend time outdoors it will get parasites, Even cats that do not hunt is at risk of getting parasites.

If your cat do hunt it will get intestinal worms, The types will be different depending on where you live.

All cats in the wild will have parasites and this is one of the reasons for why cats in the wild have a significant shorter life span than our house cats.

My cat is an outdoor/indoor cat and I treat her for intestinal worms every 6 months this is a little less than what is needed for my cat to keep her free of intestinal parasites as she do hunt a lot.

Cats are at risk of getting external parasites too, Like lice-ticks-fleas so you need to keep an eye on this and administer treatment when it is needed.

And yes companies make a living by selling medication for animals in the same way as they do by selling medication for people.

Comment: Are there any scientific evidence that dewormed cats live longer/better? Or it is just our vet-induced perception?

Comment: @Karlom that is an entire new question you might ask here.i will have to do some research to find this information.

Comment: It's not. I asked `I'm wondering if this is absolutely necessary?` implying that I need some hard (scientific) evidence that deworming is required. You gave your opinion, which if fine and I appreciate it. But  it does not answer the question, hence I did not picked it.

Comment: several types of intestinal parasites can infect people so you or your family might get infected from your cat if you do not deworm it.i do not want to get worms so i treat my cat,it is easier than it is to treat my family against worms of different types :)